# Invoke a function once if using along with ng-repeat using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a function to be invoked only once when it is being used along with ng-if and ng-repeat.

```
 <td ng-if="!vm.monthView && vm.yearView=='contract-year'" nginit="vm.ContractYearBaselines()" class="baseline-data-field"  ng-repeat="baselineDatum in baseline.data track by $index"restrict-to="[0-9]">
                {{baselineDatum}}</td>
```

The function vm.ContractYearBaselines() is being invoked as many times the ng-repeat executes......thereby the function having the API calls as many times.....can we restrict the function to be executed only once along with ng-repeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a boolean variable inside the function and based on it you can execute it,

```
vm.executed = false;
vm.ContractYearBaselines = function(){
   if(!vm.executed)
   {
      your conditions;
     vm.executed = true;
   }  
}
```